# How print all rows after select specific value in row by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I select minimum low price from these dataframe
but I want print all rows after a row have minimum price.
I try something but the result only specific row.

```
data = client.get_historical_klines(symbol=i, interval="1h", start_str="24 hours ago",
                                    end_str=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                                                                   
df.columns = columns
df["Volume"] = df["Quote_Volume"]
for x in range(6, 12):
    del df[columns[x]]
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],unit='ms')
df['Tiker'] = i
df = df.set_index('Tiker')
df["Close"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Close"])
df["Open"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Open"])
df["High"] = pd.to_numeric(df["High"])
df["Low"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Low"])
df["Volume"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Volume"])
df["LOW"] = df["Low"]==df["Low"].min()

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

df_new = df[df["Low"]==df["Low"].min()] or
df_new= df.loc[df["Low"]==df["Low"].min()]

print(df_new)